# Initialization of a structure containing string

Tags: c, string, structure

In the following program line 5 gives an error but 11 does not while both are doing same things i.e              initialization of a string with 0?
I very well know that it gives compiler error.My doubt exactly is if line 5 gives error then why line 11 doesnot?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char name[20]=0;   //This should also run if line 11 runs without an error where string is being initialized by zero.
    struct node
    {
        char name[20];
        int no;
    };
    struct node a={0};
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to initialize a compound object (arrays, structures, unions) then you need to put the values inside curly braces `{}`. So you need to write

```
char name[20] = { 0 };  /* Or '\0' */
```

Strings are a special case, where the compiler handles that, so you can write e.g.

```
char name[20] = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

Line 5 should be:

```
char name[20] = {'\0'};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just forget the bracket. try to compile like that `char name[20]={0}`
Even if `name` is not a struct, it's an array and that's the reason why you have to add these brackets to initialize

Answer (score 0):

the lines aren't the same.

line 5 is trying to initialize a char array with an integer.

line 11 initialize a struct with the string initialized with 0 - '\0'